# vscode double click highlights word and sentence

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I double click a word in vscode it gets highlighted and selected, as it should. But something else happens sometimes: the whole sentence gets highlighted. **Is there a way for me to easily select the whole highlighted sentence?**

In the picture I double clicked the word "test", as you can see it is highlighted in a different color, but the whole sentence is also highlighted. Only the word "test" is selected.

(this is in a javascript file but it probably does the same in other formats)

[image: print screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

```json
    "selectby.regexes": {
      "SelectSentence": {
        "backward": "'",
        "forward": "'",
        "forwardInclude": false,
        "backwardInclude": false
      }
    }
```

You can use the command palette command: **Select text range based on regex** and select `SelectSentence` from the list

Or setup a keybinding

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+f9", // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": ["SelectSentence"]
}
```